LWC Datatable Filtering
I'm struggling to filter my datatable whilst using the infinite scrolling features. The component seems to be duplicating rows, and also not triggering the infinite scrolling after applying a filter.
I've killed hours on this now, and I'm convinced its something simple but I'm just not sure what so I'm hoping somebody can help...
Background:
I have a LWC which shows a datatable (its custom to enable custom data types) that queries a Custom Metadata Type on the wire. Once loaded, @track data is populated with the results. It loads the first 5 results, and then if there are more the datatable calls the onloadmore() event handler to populate the available space in the table to 200px. This all works fine.
I'm using an open source project as a child component to provide the filtering: https://github.com/SFDC-Hub/lwc-dynamic-datable-filter.
My JS:
    import { LightningElement, wire, track, api } from 'lwc';
import getMetadata from '@salesforce/apex/processMetadataForDCAlerts.getMetadata';
import parseChangedMetadata from '@salesforce/apex/processMetadataForDCAlerts.parseChangedMetadata';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { subscribe, unsubscribe } from 'lightning/empApi';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import getPicklistValues from '@salesforce/apex/processMetadataForDCAlerts.getPicklistValues'

const columns = [
    { label: 'Data Cloud Name', fieldName: 'data_cloud__Data_Cloud_Record_Name__c', displayReadOnlyIcon: true },
    { label: 'Data Cloud Type', fieldName: 'data_cloud__Data_Cloud_Type__c', displayReadOnlyIcon: true },
    {
        label: 'Type', fieldName: 'data_cloud__Notification_Type__c', type: 'customPicklist', editable: true,
        typeAttributes: {
            options: { fieldName: 'picklistOptionsType' },
            value: { fieldName: 'data_cloud__Notification_Type__c' },
            context: { fieldName: 'data_cloud__Data_Cloud_Record_Name__c' }
        }
    },
    {
        label: 'Frequency', fieldName: 'data_cloud__Notification_Frequency__c', type: 'customPicklist', editable: true,
        typeAttributes: {
            options: { fieldName: 'picklistOptionsFrequency' },
            value: { fieldName: 'data_cloud__Notification_Frequency__c' },
            context: { fieldName: 'data_cloud__Data_Cloud_Record_Name__c' }
        }
    },
    { label: 'Title', fieldName: 'data_cloud__Notification_Title__c', editable: true },
    { label: 'Body', fieldName: 'data_cloud__Notification_Body__c', wrapText: true, editable: true },
    { label: 'Email Template Name', fieldName: 'data_cloud__Notification_Template_Name__c', editable: true },
    { label: 'Permission Set to Notify', fieldName: 'data_cloud__Permission_Set_Name__c', editable: true },
    {
        label: 'Enabled?', fieldName: 'data_cloud__Enable_Notifications__c', type: 'customToggle',
        typeAttributes: {
            value: { fieldName: 'data_cloud__Enable_Notifications__c' },
            context: { fieldName: 'data_cloud__Data_Cloud_Record_Name__c' },
        }
    }
];

export default class DisplayMetadataforDCAlerts extends LightningElement {

    @track _wiredResult;
    @track data = [];
    @track errors = {};
    @track picklistOptionsFrequency;
    @track picklistOptionsType;
    @track loadedPicklist;

    @api noRecords = false;
    @api totalRecordCount;

    @api
    get showTable() {
        if (this.totalRecordCount > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @api valueDCType;
    get optionsDCType() {
        return [
            { label: 'Data Stream', value: 'DataStream' },
            { label: 'Data Transform', value: 'MktDataTransform' },
            { label: 'Identity Resolution', value: 'IdentityResolution' },
            { label: 'Calculated Insight', value: 'MktCalculatedInsight' },
            { label: 'Segments', value: 'MarketSegment' },
            { label: 'Activations', value: 'MarketSegmentActivation' }
        ];
    }

    @api valueNotifType;
    get optionsNotifType() {
        return [
            { label: 'Notification Bell', value: 'Notification Bell' },
            { label: 'Email', value: 'Email' }
        ];
    }
    tableElement;
    columns = columns;
    saveDraftValues = [];
    mergedData = [];
    picklistValsType = [];
    picklistValsFrequency = [];
    channelName = '/event/data_cloud__DeploymentStatusCallback__e';
    subscription = {};
    showSpinner = true;

    queryLimit = 5;
    queryOffset = 0;
    @api loadMoreStatus;
    
    filters = [
        { label: 'Data Cloud Type', type: 'picklist', api: 'data_cloud__Data_Cloud_Type__c' },
        { label: 'Notification Type', type: 'picklist', api: 'data_cloud__Notification_Type__c' },
        { label: 'Notification Frequency', type: 'picklist', api: 'data_cloud__Notification_Frequency__c' }
    ];

    connectedCallback() {
        this.showSpinner = true;

        var fields = {'fields': ['data_cloud__Notification_Frequency__c', 'data_cloud__Notification_Type__c']};
        getPicklistValues({ objectName: 'data_cloud__Data_Cloud_Notification_Feature__mdt', picklistFieldNames: JSON.stringify(fields)}).then(fields => {
            for(var field in fields) {
                let values = fields[field];
                values.forEach(value => {
                    if(field == 'data_cloud__Notification_Type__c') {
                        this.picklistValsType.push({ label: value, value: value });
                    }
                    else {  
                        this.picklistValsFrequency.push({ label: value, value: value });
                    }
                })
            }
            this.picklistOptionsType = this.picklistValsType;
            this.picklistOptionsFrequency = this.picklistValsFrequency;
            this.loadedPicklist = true;
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log('Error retrieving the picklist vals: ' + error);
        });   
    }

    _showToastEvent(variant, title, message) {
        const event = new ShowToastEvent({
            title,
            message,
            variant
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

    //Subscribe to a Platform event when a deployment is scheduled
    _handleSubscribe() {

        //Callback invoked whenever a new event message is received, it contains the payload of the new message received
        const messageCallback = response => {
            //console.log('New message received: ', JSON.stringify(response));
            var jsonArray = Array.from(Object.values(response));
            var recordId = jsonArray[0].payload.data_cloud__RecordId__c;
            var deploymentStatus = jsonArray[0].payload.data_cloud__Status__c;
            var failureCount = jsonArray[0].payload.data_cloud__Failure_Count__c;
            if (deploymentStatus == 'Succeeded') {
                this._showToastEvent('success', 'Deployment Complete', 'The deployment with Job Id ' + recordId + ' completed successfully.');
            }
            else {
                var failureMessage = failureCount > 1 ? 'records' : 'record';
                this._showToastEvent('error', 'Deployment Failed', 'The deployment with Job Id ' + recordId + ' failed. ' + failureCount + ' ' + failureMessage + '  failed to deploy. Please review the Deployment Status in Setup for full details.');
            }

            refreshApex(this._wiredResult).then(() => { //Refresh the cached data.
                console.log('Apex data refreshed');
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error refreshing data table values: ', error);
            });

            this._handleUnsubscribe();
        };

        //Invoke subscribe method of empApi. Pass reference to messageCallback
        subscribe(this.channelName, -1, messageCallback).then((response) => {
            //console.log('Subscription request sent to: ', JSON.stringify(response.channel)); //Response contains the subscription information on subscribe call
            this.subscription = response;
        });
    }

    //Handles unsubscribe after receiving an event
    _handleUnsubscribe() {
        unsubscribe(this.subscription, (response) => {
            //console.log('unsubscribe() response: ', JSON.stringify(response)); // Response is true for successful unsubscribe
        });
    }

    handleLoadMoreData(event) {

        console.log('in the handlemore function!');
        //Display a spinner to signal that data is being loaded
        if(event.target){
            event.target.isLoading = true;
        }

        this.tableElement = event.target;

        //Display "Loading" when more data is being loaded
        this.loadMoreStatus = 'Loading';
        this.queryOffset = this.queryOffset + this.queryLimit;
        
        console.log('this.queryLimit in load more: ' + this.queryLimit);
        console.log('this.queryOffset in load more: ' + this.queryOffset);

        getMetadata({loadedPicklist: this.loadedPicklist, offsetRecords: this.queryOffset, limitRecords: this.queryLimit}).then((data) => {
            //Appends new data to the end of the table

            console.log('data returned from load more: ' + JSON.stringify(data.metaRecords));

            this.data = this.data.concat(data.metaRecords); 
            console.log('New data after loadmore: ' + JSON.stringify(this.data));
            this.loadMoreStatus = '';

            if (data.metaRecords.length === 0) {
                this.tableElement.enableInfiniteLoading = false;
                this.loadMoreStatus = 'No more data to load';
            }

            if(this.tableElement) {
                this.tableElement.isLoading = false;
            }
        });


    }

    handleToggleSelect(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        let toggleid = event.detail.data.context;
        let toggleValue = event.detail.data.value;
        let updatedItem = { data_cloud__Data_Cloud_Record_Name__c: toggleid, data_cloud__Enable_Notifications__c: toggleValue };
        this.updateDraftValuesAndData(updatedItem);
        this.updateColumnData(updatedItem);
    }

    //Update draft values to trigger the Save/Cancel footer.
    updateDraftValuesAndData(updateItem) {
        let draftValueChanged = false;
        let copyDraftValues = [...this.saveDraftValues];

        copyDraftValues.forEach(item => {
            if (item.data_cloud__Data_Cloud_Record_Name__c === updateItem.data_cloud__Data_Cloud_Record_Name__c) {
                for (let field in updateItem) {
                    item[field] = updateItem[field];
                }
                draftValueChanged = true;
            }
        });

        if (draftValueChanged) {
            this.saveDraftValues = [...copyDraftValues];
        } else {
            this.saveDraftValues = [...copyDraftValues, updateItem];
        }
    }

    //Update retrieved data with the changed checkbox value. 
    updateColumnData(updatedItem) {
        let copyData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data));

        copyData.forEach(item => {
            if (item.data_cloud__Data_Cloud_Record_Name__c === updatedItem.data_cloud__Data_Cloud_Record_Name__c) {
                for (let field in updatedItem) {
                    item[field] = updatedItem[field];
                }
            }
        });

        this.data = [...copyData];
    }

    errorHandler(title, messages, fieldNames) {
        let rowError = {};
        rowError['title'] = title;
        rowError['messages'] = messages;
        rowError['fieldNames'] = fieldNames;
        return rowError;
    }

    //Save the changed records by scheduling a deployment.
    handleSave(event) {
        let mergedData = [];
        
        //Merge the draft data with rest of the row. We can then use it for error handling.
        mergedData.push(this.data.map((record) => (
            {
            ...record,
            ...(event.detail.draftValues.find((value) => value.data_cloud__Data_Cloud_Record_Name__c === record.data_cloud__Data_Cloud_Record_Name__c))
            }
        )));

        //Custom Error handling. Yuck!
        this.errors = {};
        let rowError = {};
        let title = 'Error';
        let messages = [];
        let fieldNames = [];
        
        this.mergedData.forEach(item => {

            //The notification type of email needs an email template. If blank, error the row.
            if (item.data_cloud__Notification_Type__c == 'Email' && item.data_cloud__Notification_Template_Name__c === undefined || item.data_cloud__Notification_Template_Name__c == '') {
                fieldNames = ['data_cloud__Notification_Template_Name__c'];
                messages = ['An email template must be specified for email type notifications'];
                rowError[item.data_cloud__Data_Cloud_Record_Name__c] = this.errorHandler(title, messages, fieldNames);
                this.errors['rows'] = rowError;
            }

            //The Notification Type of Notification needs title/body. If either are blank, error the row.
            if (item.data_cloud__Notification_Type__c == 'Notification Bell') {
                messages = [];
                fieldNames = [];
                if (item.data_cloud__Notification_Title__c == '' || item.data_cloud__Notification_Title__c === undefined) {
                    fieldNames.push('data_cloud__Notification_Title__c');
                    messages.push('A notification title must be specified for email type notifications');
                    rowError[item.data_cloud__Data_Cloud_Record_Name__c] = this.errorHandler(title, messages, fieldNames);
                    this.errors['rows'] = rowError;
                }

                if (item.data_cloud__Notification_Body__c == '' || item.data_cloud__Notification_Body__c === undefined) {
                    fieldNames.push('data_cloud__Notification_Body__c');
                    messages.push('A notification body must be specified for email type notifications');
                    rowError[item.data_cloud__Data_Cloud_Record_Name__c] = this.errorHandler(title, messages, fieldNames);
                    this.errors['rows'] = rowError;
                }
            }
        });

        //Only schedule a deployment if there is no validation errors.
        if (Object.keys(this.errors).length === 0 && this.errors.constructor === Object) {
            this.showSpinner = true;
            this._handleSubscribe();
            parseChangedMetadata({ jsonString: JSON.stringify(event.detail.draftValues)}).then(result => {
                this.saveDraftValues = [];
                this.data = this.mergedData;
                this._showToastEvent('success', 'Deployment Scheduled', 'The Deployment Job Id is ' + result + '. You will be notified when the deployment completes.');
            }).catch(error => {
                this._showToastEvent('error', 'Deployment Failed', error.body.message);
                this._handleUnsubscribe();
            });
            this.showSpinner = false;
        }
    }

    handleFilter(event) {
        
        console.log('in the handleFilter function!');
        console.log('this.data before filter applied: ' + JSON.stringify(this.data));
        console.log('Filtered data: ' + JSON.stringify(event.detail.data));

        this.data = event.detail.data;

        //Reset the offset. Just in case we need to call handleLoadMoreData() again.
        this.queryOffset = 0; 


        //Re-enable the infinite scroll.
        this.tableElement = this.template.querySelector('c-custom-Datatable');
        /*window.scrollTop({
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            behavior: "smooth",
          });*/
        if (this.data.length === 0) {
            this.tableElement.enableInfiniteLoading = false;
            this.loadMoreStatus = 'No more data to load';
            this.tableElement.isLoading = false;
        }
        else {
            this.tableElement.enableInfiniteLoading = true;
            this.loadMoreStatus = '';
            this.tableElement.isLoading = false;    
        }
    }

    //Add the picklist values to the rows of data before outputting it to the datatable.
    addPicklistVals(tempData) {
        return tempData.map((curItem) => {
            let type =  this.picklistValsType;
            let freq = this.picklistValsFrequency;

            return {
                ...curItem, 
                picklistOptionsType: type,
                picklistOptionsFrequency: freq
            }
        });
    }

    //Load the metadata into the data table.
    //Pass a dud reactive variable to stop the wire trying to load data before we have the confirmed picklist values, otherwise the picklist options aren't loaded properly.
    //NOTE: Other variables can't be reactive, as they are re-calculated causing an unnecessary reload.
    @wire(getMetadata, {loadedPicklist: '$loadedPicklist', offsetRecords: 0, limitRecords: 5})
    wiredMetadata(result) {
        this._wiredResult = result;
        if (result.data) {

            //this.totalRecords = result.data.length;
            this.totalRecordCount = result.data.totalRecordCount;
            this.data = this.addPicklistVals(result.data.metaRecords);

            if (this.totalRecordCount === 0) {
                this.noRecords = true;
            }

            this.showSpinner = false;
        }
        else if (result.error) {
            console.log('Error loading data for table: ' + result.error);
            this.data = undefined;
        }
    }
}

My HTML Template:
<template>
    <lightning-card icon-name="utility:alert" title="Data Cloud Change Notification Settings">
        <template lwc:if={showSpinner}>
            <div class="slds-var-p-around_x-small">
                <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading..." role="status"></lightning-spinner>
            </div>
        </template>
        <div lwc:if={showTable}>

            <div class="slds-var-p-around_x-small slds-grid">Change existing settings for Data Cloud notifications, then
                click Save to deploy them. You will be notified when the deployment has finished.</div>
            <div class="slds-var-p-around_x-small slds-grid">Filter the table by Data Cloud Type &amp; Notification Type.
                The results are updated when you click Apply Filter.</div>

            <!-- Component as found here: https://github.com/SFDC-Hub/lwc-dynamic-datable-filter -->
            <!-- Minor fixes to alignment applied to button using custom CSS--> 
            <c-dynamic-Filter filters={filters} tdata={data} onfilter={handleFilter}>></c-dynamic-Filter>

            <!-- Table Component. Using a custom implementation to support picklists, and toggles -->
            <!-- Height is set to a fixed height to control infinite loading features -->
            <div style="height: 200px">
                <c-custom-Datatable key-field="data_cloud__Data_Cloud_Record_Name__c" data={data}
                    draft-values={saveDraftValues} columns={columns} errors={errors} onsave={handleSave}
                    hide-checkbox-column show-row-number-column="true" wrap-text-max-lines="2" ontoggleselect={handleToggleSelect} 
                    enable-infinite-loading="true" onloadmore={handleLoadMoreData} load-more-offset="10">
                </c-custom-Datatable>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-var-p-around_x-small slds-align_absolute-center">
                {loadMoreStatus}
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div lwc:if={noRecords}>
            <div class="slds-var-p-around_x-small"><lightning-icon size="small" icon-name="utility:ban"
                    alternative-text="No Records Found"></lightning-icon> No Data Cloud notification settings are
                configured.</div>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>

It loads fine, you can see that record 4 is just off the screen and scrolling down shows the "Loading" footer, which triggers the load of the remaining records. A total of 7.

Next, apply a filter. Notification Type = Email. This should show 1 result in my dataset. However, I see 3. 1 matching the filter and 2 other records which are actually loaded because the onloadmore event handler is called.
The getMetdata call via an Apex controller gets 2 records because that is the remaining dataset to load before I applied a filter. I think its 2 because the initial load returned  5 of 7, load more returns the remaining 2.
Q1: So, I think I need to filter these results again with the applied filter. But I don't understand why - The this.data variable is tracked so this should work I thought. Maybe I need to loop the data in a map? Presumably the results of this would then set this.data to the correct rows applying the filter?
Q2: Maybe I need to branch off on a separate topic/question for this but it is related. Where I may have loaded all records, the infinite load flag is set to false. Therefore in my handleFilter() method, I reset these flags. The issue I have here is that the datatable remains in its current position, rather than scrolling to the top again giving consistent behaviour as with no filtering i.e loading first 5 records. I've commented the attempt out above, but I tried to use window.scrollTop() approach, but that returns the whole browser window to the top, not the current component's datatable. I tried changing window to the table element that I select through a querySelect but that errors. I also know there is an aura solution: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/ui:scrollerWrapper/documentation, but I don't have any experience with implementing this so is this worth pursuing further or is there a more native JS solution that might work?
